# Automatic verify the Fingeprint of a user [BLOB]

Tags: mysql, vb.net, blob, fingerprint

Hi? I have here fingerprint scanner. I want to automatically verified user's fingerprint when they are touching the scanner but I cant.

I have here codes but before you verify the fingerprint if it correct, you need to put first his/her userID.

This is my codes:

```
Private Sub SaveButton_Click() Handles SaveButton.Click
        Using files As New IO.MemoryStream
            Template.Serialize(files)
            objconn.Open()
            If Not Template Is Nothing Then
                Dim cmd = New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO employeefp " +
                                  "SET id=@id, " +
                                  "FP=@FP " + 
" ", objconn)

                cmd.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("@id", TextBox1.Text))
                cmd.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("@FP", Template.Bytes))

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                objconn.Close()
                MessageBox.Show("Template Successfuly Saved.", "Finger Enrolled")
            End If
        End Using

 End Sub
```

And this my verify button codes:

```
   Private Sub VerifyButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles VerifyButton.Click
        If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Please input id no.", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
        Else
            objconn.Open()
            Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM employeefp where id ='" & TextBox1.Text & "'", objconn)
            Dim rdr As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            rdr.Read()
            If rdr.HasRows Then
                Dim Verifier As New VerificationForm
                Verifier.Verify(Template)
            Else
                MsgBox("The id doesn`t exist", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
            End If
        End If
        objconn.Close()
    End Sub
```

i thought its all about in `templates.bytes` but i don't know what will I do.
Thanks in advance. Hope you will help me.

Comment: It sound like your reader code does not check the fingerprint against all fingerprints in DB but checks in the fingerprint for userid X is a match. I.E. you need to put in ID and then scan fingerprint. If ID exists if will then go on to verifying if the fingerprint matches for that User ID.